# Juvenile book about limited magic in a parallel world and a “chosen” girl that can use unlimited magic

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

About 10-15 years ago, I read a saga of books, mostly young adult fantasy I think, about a girl discovering that she can use magic. She can travel to a parallel world where magic exists more commonly (but there is more like a medieval style), but is limited (because of an accident or similar) for everyone except for her.

On the first book they tell her that she has to find her lost brother, because he is the chosen one that will free the limited magic. However at the end she discovers that her brother can barely do magic and she’s the chosen one. I don’t remember much from the other books, other than the metaphorical “wall” that limits magic is described as a wall of thorns.

Also, she has a boy friend who has a lot of brothers. They both end up in a river somehow when traveling from one world to the other.

Comment: Does the boyfriend have six brothers and is a seventh son of a seventh son maybe? https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MagicalSeventhSon

Comment: @jo1storm I don't remember, he may be, but if he is, it doesn't have any impact in the story until at least the second book. I've checked the link, but none of the examples are what I'm looking for. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Could be the Ewilan saga, if you read French

Comment: @clef YES! Thank you very much! Not french but spanish, it reached here too. If you put it like an answer, I'll accept it, if you want. Thank you!

Comment: Done, and feel free to edit my answer to make it more accurate once you read the books again ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like the Ewilan saga (not translated to English atm as far as I know).

It's the story of a young teenage girl, Ewilan, who manages to travel worlds accidentally with her best friend, Salim, and discovers more about herself in the process of exploring this magical world on a quest for more information and her brother (if I remember the first book correctly).

Comment: Apparently Amazon sells an English version. I think it's a graphic novel

Comment: It is not originally a graphic novel though :)